# RegEx for capturing group not recognized

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group, named-captures

I have the following Regex:

```
(?:\/(?<root>family-resources|employer-resources|newsroom|text-pages))?\/(?:(?<path>[0-9A-z=\-\s]+\/?)+)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set up two named capture groups - `root` and `path`. However, when running this and checking the match groups, there is no `root` group - only `path`.

Using C#:

```
root = match.Groups["root"]?.Value ?? "Text Pages"; // Returns an empty string as the root group is missing.
```

I was able to reproduce this by running the Regex pattern on https://regex101.com/.

If you put in the following test string:

```
/sitecore/content/Corporate-New/home/employer-resources/back-up-care
```

You'll notice you only get one named capture group back - `path`.
Why is `root` not being returned?

It definitely seems like I'm using the right syntax for a named capture group. I've tried adding parentheses both outside the capture group and inside the regex pattern, and neither worked. I was thinking maybe the Regex pattern wasn't being understood.

[image: regex101 result screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex:

```
(?:.*\/(?<root>family\-resources|employer\-resources|newsroom|text\-pages))?\/(?:(?<path>[0-9A-z=\-\s]+\/?)+)
```

I added an anti-slash in front of each `-` since they are reserved, and a `.*` at the beginning to accept any path before your first group.

[image: RegEx]

`(?: )` requires everything between the parenthesis to be in the non-captured group. The `.*` allows the beginning of the path to match the pattern. Otherwise, the first slash encountered will match and stop the parsing (at sitecore).

Another solution would be to use a look-behind:

```
(?<=\/)(?<root>family\-resources|employer\-resources|newsroom|text\-pages)?\/(?:(?<path>[0-9A-z=\-\s]+\/?)+)
```

This is slightly more advanced, but is closer to what you tried to achieve.

Comment: That did the trick, specifically the `.*` part. Is there any particular reason why that was needed? Regardless, marked as solved... Thank you!

Comment: I added an explanation, and an alternate, more advanced, solution.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense.